# How to display all sub string found in cut command

Tags: grep, cut

I've a grep command

```
grep -o 'ITEM+[^ ]*' "file.txt"
```

And the returned string is like this

```
ITEM+12345678::hashtext_20191030::ITEM+87654321::hashmap_20191030::ITEM+12348765::hashvalue_20191001
```

So when i add the cut command,

```
grep -o 'ITEM+[^ ]*' "file.txt" | cut -c 5-12
```

I only get one result:

```
12345678
```

How do i make the result to be something like this:

```
12345678
87654321
12348765
```

Comment: it's better if you post a testable fragment of your `file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `grep` only returns one line, the `[^ ]*` pattern matches `12345678::hashtext_20191030::ITEM+…` and the rest of the line until a space character is found. If you only want to match `ITEM+` and the following digits, use

```
grep -o 'ITEM+[^:]*' file.txt
```

or

```
grep -o 'ITEM+[0-9]*' file.txt
```

and you will get multiple results.

You should get all the numbers with

```
grep -o 'ITEM+[^:]*' file.txt | cut -c 6-
```

which returns the 6th character until the end of the line.

Comment: If using GNU grep, the comand: `grep -oP 'ITEM\+\K[0-9]{8}'` will extract the numbers directly, no cut required.